# Same data saved generate different images - Python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, save

I have in my code two methods to save images data, one to just save it values in greyscale and another one to generate a heat map image:

```
def save_image(self, name):
    """
    Save an image data in PNG format
    :param name: the name of the file
    """
    graphic = Image.new("RGB", (self.width, self.height))
    putpixel = graphic.putpixel
    for x in range(self.width):
        for y in range(self.height):
            color = self.data[x][y]
            color = int(Utils.translate_range(color, self.range_min, self.range_max, 0, 255))
            putpixel((x, y), (color, color, color))
    graphic.save(name + ".png", "PNG")

def generate_heat_map_image(self, name):
    """
    Generate a heat map of the image
    :param name: the name of the file
    """
    #self.normalize_image_data()
    plt.figure()
    fig = plt.imshow(self.data, extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
    plt.colorbar(fig)
    plt.savefig(name+".png")
    plt.close()
```

The class that represents my data is this:

```
class ImageData:
def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.data = []
    for i in range(width):
        self.data.append([0] * height)
```

Passing the same data for both methods

> ContourMap.save_image("ImagesOutput/VariabilityOfGradients/ContourMap")
>       ContourMap.generate_heat_map_image("ImagesOutput/VariabilityOfGradients/ContourMapHeatMap")

I get one image rotated in relation to the other.

Method 1:

[image: save_image]

Method 2:

[image: generate_heat_map_image]

I don't get it why, but I have to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using [`putpixel`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putpixel) in the first place? That's the slowest possible way to build up an image, especially in older PIL/Pillow versions. Why not just translate the array with a single vectorized operation, then just copy the whole thing at once? Or use `ImageDraw`? Or just about anything else?

Comment: I just gave you two different tips, as well as a link to the docs, which have more extensive tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the data are in row-major format, but you're iterating as if it were in column-major format, which rotates the whole thing by -90 degrees.

The quick fix is to replace this line:

```
color = self.data[x][y]
```

… with this one:

```
color = self.data[y][x]
```

(Although presumably `data` is an array, so you really ought to be using `self.data[y, x]` instead.)

A clearer fix is:

```
for row in range(self.height):
    for col in range(self.width):
        color = self.data[row][col]
        color = int(Utils.translate_range(color, self.range_min, self.range_max, 0, 255))
        putpixel((col, row), (color, color, color))
```

---

This may not be entirely clear from the pyplot documentation, but if you look at [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), it explains that it takes an array-like object of shape (n, m) and displays it as an MxN image.

Comment: So I could initialize my data like this: self.data = [] for i in range(height): self.data.append([0] * width) to fix it? Sorry, but I'm new with Python.

Comment: @pceccon: Are you trying to get the `imshow` version rotated to match your `putpixel` version, or the other way around? If `imshow` is correct, leave your data alone, and change the way you loop over it in `save_image` (as in my answer). If `ifshow` is wrong, change the way you build the data.