# Plotting with Matplotlib results in -90 rotated plots - Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, rotation

I've had this kind of "problem" when plotting with **Matplotlib** frequently ([Same data saved generate different images - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133904/same-data-saved-generate-different-images-python)). 
As an example, I created a vector field with a numpy array like this:

```
def generate_divergent_free_component(sigma, x_dim, y_dim, steps):
    divergent_free_vector_field_x = numpy.zeros((steps, steps), float)
    divergent_free_vector_field_y = numpy.zeros((steps, steps), float)

    u0 = numpy.random.uniform()
    x0 = 1.0 + sigma * u0
    y0 = sigma * u0

    dx = x_dim/float(steps)
    dy = y_dim/float(steps)

    for x, y in product(range(steps), range(steps)):
        x_norm = -x_dim/2.0 + x * dx
        y_norm = -y_dim/2.0 + y * dy
        exp0 = -(math.pow(x_norm - x0, 2) + math.pow(y_norm - y0, 2)) / 2.0

        divergent_free_vector_field_x[x, y] = -(x_norm - x0) * math.exp(exp0)
        divergent_free_vector_field_y[x, y] = -(y_norm - y0) * math.exp(exp0)

    return divergent_free_vector_field_x, divergent_free_vector_field_y
```

I made some tests and it seems to me that **ndarrays** follow row-major order and I am iterating over them following this pattern.

However, when plotting with **Matplotlib**, I get the image rotated 90 degrees counter-clock wise.

```
def plot_streamlines(file_path, x_dim, y_dim, steps, vector_field_x, vector_field_y, scalar_field=None):
    plt.figure()

    y, x = numpy.mgrid[-x_dim/2:x_dim/2:steps*1j, -y_dim/2:y_dim/2:steps*1j]

    plt.figure()

    # x, y : 1d arrays, an evenly spaced grid.
    # u, v : 2d arrays
    # x and y-velocities. Number of rows should match length of y, and the number of columns should match x.
    plt.streamplot(x, y, vector_field_x, vector_field_y, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

As an example, I got this image:

[image]

But I was expecting (and another programs such as Matlab) the image like this (I just rotated it in my computer now, but I was expecting that point that I circled as the following image shows):

[image]

So I'm wondering if Matplotlib works or expects column-major order or something like this... I'm just trying to understand how this properly works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `plt.streamplot` wants the `divergent_free_vector_field` arrays to be indexed `[y, x]`, instead of `[x, y]`.

A good test would be to use different step sizes in `x` and `y`. You should get an `AssertionError` on the grid shape when you try to plot, because it's expecting the number of rows to be same as the size of `y`, and the number of columns to be the same as the size of `x`.

Try changing it to this:

```
divergent_free_vector_field_x = numpy.zeros((steps_y, steps_x), float)
divergent_free_vector_field_y = numpy.zeros((steps_y, steps_x), float)
...
divergent_free_vector_field_x[y, x] = -(x_norm - x0) * math.exp(exp0)
divergent_free_vector_field_y[y, x] = -(y_norm - y0) * math.exp(exp0)
```

Comment: It's what I supposed, but I couldn't find it in the documentation. Now I would like to plot my vector field with two different methods and I can't make them match (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965477/plotting-vector-fields-with-two-different-methods-quiver-streamplot-resultin). I'm kind in doubt to insist or not in Matploblib. :S

Comment: @pceccon I agree the documentation is not very clear. It says this about u and v:
*u*, *v* : 2d arrays x and y-velocities. **Number of rows should match length of y, and the number of columns should match x.**